# Cannot connection Oracle Database after using Docker container

Tags: database, oracle, docker, save, load

```
Docker version: 1.10
Env : CentOS 7
```

In my local machine, I deploy my application to docker image to container, and then save as tar file. And then copy the tar file to testing environment and run the docker load command to install the image and the create container with that image.

However, when the application is running, it cannot be connect to Database that never happen in my local machine. And the testing environment can be able to ping to the DB server.

Below is the error message. Could anyone tell me whether it is necessary to open any port for docker to connect Database or any suggestion ?Thanks you very much !!

```
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:498)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConn`enter code here`ection.java:553)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:151)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:89)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:1629)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeOneConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:519)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:479)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:360)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:395)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:179)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:157)


Below is the docker file:

    enter code here

FROM centos
EXPOSE 8001 9001
RUN yum update -y && \ 
    curl --insecure --junk-session-cookies --location --remote-name --silent --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u74-b02/jdk-8u74-linux-x64.rpm && \ 
    yum localinstall -y jdk-8u74-linux-x64.rpm && \ 
    rm jdk-8u74-linux-x64.rpm && \ 
    yum clean all 
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default \ 
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \ 
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 
WORKDIR /MCI3
COPY MCI3/ /MCI3/
CMD ["java","-jar","/MCI3/cs-mci3.jar", "-Xmx100m"]

------------------------------------------------------------
In my local machine:
docker build -t [IMAGE_NAME] .
docker save -o [TAR_FILE_NAME] [IMAGE_NAME:IMAGE_TAG]

After create the tar file then copy it to the testing env( no any internet) :

sudo docker load --input [PATH_TO_TAR_FILE] 
sudo docker run -p 9001:9001 -p 8001:8001 --name cs-mci3_container cs-mci3_image
```

Comment: so did you link the oracle dabase (is it docker container as well?) to your application container, can you show us the `Dockerfile` and `docker run` command as well?

Comment: I haven't did any oracle database setting in docker file. The application is used spring framework to initial the database instance. And it can be connect to db in my local vm. Is it need to do any configuration for connect db in docker container ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the CMD as below, either one or both.

1. CMD `["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/MCI3/cs-mci3.jar", "-Xmx100m"]`
2. set docker `--mtu=1400`.